# Mono exception calling native code

Tags: c#, mono

we are programming an multiplatform program with mono.

now i want to use some native code on a mac.

I found the NSLocal class and wanted to use:

```
string test = NSLocale.CurrentLocale.CountryCode;
```

but i run into an exception when the program is hitting this code:

> Message: An exception of Type System.ArgumentNullException occured.
>   Message was: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj

Stacktrace:

> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_monitor_enter_v4_internal
>   (object,intptr) at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.TryGetNSObject (System.IntPtr
>   ptr, System.Boolean evenInFinalizerQueue) [0x00009] in
>   <1a80b695c02b4e7dbda63e331ae0ac27>:0

other code like:

```
    string[] test2 = NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes;
```

also runs into an exception:

> Message: An exception of type System.TypeInitializationException
>   occured. Message was: The type initializer for 'Foundation.NSString'
>   threw an exception.

Stacktrace:

> at Foundation.NSArray.StringArrayFromHandle (System.IntPtr handle)
>   [0x00047] in <1a80b695c02b4e7dbda63e331ae0ac27>:0 at
>   Foundation.NSLocale.get_ISOCountryCodes() [0x00010] in
>   <1a80b695c02b4e7dbda63e331ae0ac27>:0

well what i'am doing wrong? when i'm calling this native code?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a `Xamarin.Mac` based application?

Comment: yes - a reference to xamarin.mac is included

Comment: A reference? Are you init'ing an app? i.e. `NSApplication.Init(); NSApplication.Main(args);`, .... registering an `NSApplicationDelegate` subclass, etc... ?

Comment: no i only using the xamarin.mac.dll file to call this native code

Comment: You might want to look at the Xamarin.Mac (and Apple's Cocoa-based) docs to understand how to initialize an `NSApplication` instance.

Comment: well but i dont want to start a NSApplication - i only want to use some native code from this dll

Comment: Those "native" calls are based upon ObjC's messaging and that requires a run loop from an NSApplication.

Comment: is there a way to do that without? - i am running an mono app and cant Switch

or can i run this Loop in an method? calling this when i Need it? or must NSApplication run at main?

Comment: @xyz-Mann have you ever been able to solve this? I'm running the same issue.